# ERROR: '~ubuntugis' user or team does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, gdal, ubuntu-20.04

I've been trying to follow the steps from [this guide](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html) to get the latest version of GDAL onto my ubuntu, unfortunately I get the error from the title when I try to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntugis/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~ubuntugis' user or team does not exist.
```

My version of ubuntu is 20.04